# How to get the response time of webservice in Objective-c

Tags: iphone, ipad, soap, response

Can any one let me know  while consuming the webservice ,how to get the response time with that,currently im getting the soap message length using the following code

```
msgLength       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
```

Can any one help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure *round trip* time on device - the time taken from when you fire the request to when it is returned.

This can be a little misleading on iPhone, because 3G connections can vary quite dramatically. If you were interested in your service's performance it would be better to do some analytics or measurement server-side.

But, if you want to measure on device you can just save the current time before you make the call, get the current time when the call is returned, and get the difference.

```
startDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval startTime = [startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

...gives you the current UNIX timestamp in seconds.

Comment: Can you tel me to get it in milliseconds

Comment: NSTimeInterval is a double: the milliseconds will be the fractional part. You've already got it there.